# jQuery convert data-* attributes to lower camel case properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery script to intialise a jQuery plugin called poshytips. I want configure the plugin using Html5 data attributes. I am repeating myself big time, can anyone come up with a better way to do this?

```
$('.poshytip-trigger').each(function (index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data();

    var options = {};

    if (data['class-name']) {
        options.className = data['class-name'];
    }

    if (data['align-x']) {
        options.alignX = data['align-x'];
    }

    if (data['align-y']) {
        options.alignY = data['align-y'];
    }

    if (data['offset-y']) {
        options.offsetY = data['offset-y'];
    }

    if (data['offset-x']) {
        options.offsetX = data['offset-x'];
    }

    $this.poshytip(options);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a for..in loop to read the data-* tags.. Also you don't need to camelcase as jQuery converts it to camelCase internally... [Source code reference](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L102).

```
$('.poshytip-trigger').each(function (index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data();
    var options = {};

    for (var keys in data) {
        options[keys] = data[keys];            
    }

    // For older versions of jQuery you can use $.camelCase function
    for (var keys in data) {
        options[$.camelCase(keys)] = data[keys];
    }

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3eeqV/)

for jQuery 1.4.4,

```
$('.poshytip-trigger').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data();
    var options = {};

    for (var keys in data) {
        options[camelCase(keys)] = data[keys];
    }
});

//copied from http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.camelCase
function camelCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/^-ms-/, "ms-").replace(/-([a-z]|[0-9])/ig, function(all, letter) {
        return (letter + "").toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

[**DEMO for 1.4.4**](http://jsfiddle.net/3eeqV/3/)

Comment: +1 this works in newer versions of jQuery. Try it out with jQuery 1.4.4 it works differently!

Comment: @superlogical yea.. what version are you using?

Comment: @superlogical Updated post for jQuery 1.4.4. Copied camelCase code from jQuery src.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this - **It does convert `offset-x` to `offsetX`:**

http://jsfiddle.net/8C4rZ/1/

HTML:

```
<p data-test="sdsd" data-test2="4434"></p>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {};

    for (var key in $("p").data()) {
       options[key] = $("p").data(key);
    }

    console.log(options);
});​
```

But I think Daniel's approach is better, since he explicitly controls which attributes gets set. This will take *all* `data-` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for in loop.

```
var array = ['class-name', 'align-x', 'align-y', 'offset-y', 'offset-x'];
for (x in array) {
    if(data[array[x]]) {
        options[array[x]] = data[array[x]];
    }
}
```

**Update:** In response to the OP's clarification, he could write something like this:

```
var Pair = function(hyphenated, camcelCased) {
    this.hyphenated = hyphenated;
    this.camelCased = camelCased;
}
var array = [
    new Pair('class-name', 'ClassName'),
    new Pair('align-x', 'alignX'),
    new Pair('align-y', 'alignY'),
    new Pair('offset-x', 'offsetX'),
    new Pair('offset-y', 'offsetY')];
var i, optionNameHyphenated, optionNameCamelCased;
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    optionNameHyphenated = array[i]['hyphenated'];
    optionNameCamelCased = array[i]['camelCased'];
    if (data[optionNameHyphenated]);
        options[optionNameCamelCased] = data[optionNameHyphenated];
}
```

Comment: But I want to convert from data-offset-x to offsetX. Using $this.data() does pull in the Html5 attributes and strips the data- part. But I need to convert offset-x to offsetX :)

Comment: @superlogical Seems like when you iterate data tag, jQuery internall had the keys changed to camelcase.. >> http://jsfiddle.net/3eeqV/ << [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10722089/297641)

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["className", "alignY", ...];
$(names).each(function(ind, name){
    var dataName = name.replace(/[A-Z]/, function(letter){
        return letter.toLowerCase();
    });
    if(data[dataName]){
        options[name] = data[dataName];
    }
});
```

Does this work? Unlike the other answers, this piece of code both convert only explicitly set attributes and keeps the options-object attribute name camelCase.